# what's the purpose of the chain_id in merge mining?

Tags: merged-mining

I'm considering adding merge mining support to coin x. Its parent chain will be coin b. In looking at the spec (https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Merged_mining_specification) and Dogecoin/Namecoin sources, I see that there is support for multiple merge-mined coins in a single coinbase payload. That's fine. I also see that I'm given a Merkle tree so that I can verify that my coin x's header's hash was in b's block. That's fine. Given that, what I don't understand is why I would care about x's slot in the Merkle tree in the specific case where multiple coins are being merge-mined. Why would I need to specify a chain_id? Why would I care if my data came back in a different slot than what I requested? Why even request a specific slot? In the Dogecoin codebase it verifies via getExpectedIndex (see https://github.com/dogecoin/dogecoin/blob/0b46a40ed125d7bf4b5a485b91350bc8bdc48fc8/src/auxpow.cpp#L153 ). How does that add to the security of this? Why not let the block creator put the merge-mined coins into a Merkle tree however it sees fit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the answer in a blog:

> it is necessary to make sure that a miner cannot mine on different
> branches of the same child blockchain, as this conflicts with the
> rules of the underlying Nakamoto consensus mechanism and would make
> double spending attacks possible. Hence, each cryptocurrency must
> specify a unique ID, which can be used to derive the leaf of the
> Merkle tree where the respective block hash must be located.

Source: https://alexeizamyatin.medium.com/a-technical-deep-dive-into-merged-mining-5b67706e1a19